# getting null value for calculating 90th percentile

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

here is my code

```
SELECT columnA, MIN(CASE WHEN seqnum >= 0.9 * cnt THEN value END) as percentile_90 

FROM (select t.*,
      row_number() over (partition by name order by value) as seqnum,
      count(*) over (partition by name) as cnt
      from my_table t
 ) t
WHERE XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
GROUP BY name
```

I got most of the percentile_90 correctly, but some of them returns null.

```
For 0.28
0.28
0.29
0.29
0.29
0.29
0.29
0.29
0.29
0.30
0.30, I get null. 

For 1.34
1.34
1.35
1.35
1.36
1.36
2.32
2.32
2.80
3.01
3.01, I can get 2.32 from my SQL.
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Presumably, `ColumnA` is `Name`.  Otherwise, the query would not parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that the `where` clause is filtering out the values that you want.

Assuming that all the values are populated, your code should return one of the values.  That is because the largest `seqnum` is `cnt` and `cnt >= 0.9*cnt` for all positive numbers.

Another possibility is that you have a `NULL` value among the values.  If so, that might be sorting last and that would be what you are getting.

But my first guess is the `where` clause.  If you put it *inside* the subquery, then the window functions will use the set of rows after filtering.  Then you should be returning appropriate values.